# Arch Linux: python and python2 are in conflict

Tags: arch-linux, python, pacman, dependencies

I've recently installed Arch Linux onto my primary (Ubuntu) computer, and it is working *really* well for me. It's fast, configurable, basically a faster version of Ubuntu.

Since `compiz-fusion` isn't installed by default, I'd like to see how much it would impact my performance, but I get this really nice and descriptive error message when I run `pacman` to install it:

```
[root@arch /]# pacman -S compiz-fusion-gtk
resolving dependencies...
looking for inter-conflicts...
:: python and python2 are in conflict (python<3). Remove python2? [y/N] n
error: unresolvable package conflicts detected
error: failed to prepare transaction (conflicting dependencies)
:: python and python2 are in conflict (python<3)
```

haven't installed `python3`, and my only installed Python version is `Python 2.7.1`, which doesn't seem to be conflicting with anything.

Google didn't turn up any results, so has anybody come across an error like this before? `compiz-fusion` isn't the only package which fails to install because of this python conflict, so quite a few nice packages (like `python-qt`) are uninstallable for me.

Any help is help for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Arch Linux, the `python` package contains python 3, and the `python2` package contains python 2.

Try `pacman -Sy python python2` first. Once both of those packages are installed, `compiz-fusion` and `python-qt` should install.

Oh, and you can't have updated your system in a while. `dbus-python` doesn't depend on the `python` package any more, but on the `python2` package (since october 2010, according to SVN).

Comment: So, is it the updated `python` ( that is, python 3) which is set to conflict with python<3, or is it `compiz-fusion-gtk` doing that? If it's the new python, that leaves @Blender out of luck, as long as anything still requires python2, right?

Comment: No. Updated packages requiring python 2 will specify a dependency on `python2`. Updated packages requiring python 3 will specify a dependency on `python`. Specifying a conflict with `python<3` is just a way to force you to update your system before installing, I guess.

Comment: Ahh, the nuances of packaging systems. So where is "_python and python2 are in conflict (python<3). Remove python2?_" coming from?

Comment: That conflict is coming from the `python2` package, which is (naturally) in conflict with older `python` packages. Upgrade `python` first, and all should be well, hopefully.

Comment: And the `python2` package is getting pulled in by one of the packages in the `compiz-fusion-gtk` group.

Comment: Ah, right, that makes perfect sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should never install a package with  `pacman -Sy $package`. It will eventually break your system, eat your kitten or worse, but you apparently did so. The move from python being python2 to python3 was made last year by the archlinux developers ([news article](http://www.archlinux.org/news/python-is-now-python-3/)).

Comment: There's no problem using `-Sy` to install stuff, as long as your system is up to date. No reason to, either, though.

Comment: Using `-Sy` to install packages **is** bad as you can see in this case. The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Installing_packages) also tells you not to do it, as do the pacman developers in the linked forum thread.

Comment: Yes, I did say "as long as your system is up to date". If it's not, you might get dependency issues, like the arch wiki says. On the other hand, like I also said in my first comment, there really isn't any point to installing via `-Sy`, so from that perspective the wiki gives good advice and I'm sorry to have wasted everyones time with my comments :P

Comment: I guess we both agree that an unexperienced user should not use `-Sy` to install a package, right? Experienced users can do it, but it's no use telling everybody it sometimes works because then everybody will start doing it.